# TV/Pinescript - Compilation error. Line 9: Syntax error at input 'TrueRange''

Tags: syntax, pine-script

```
indicator("sigbars")
study("Significant Bar gku", shorttitle="Significant Bar", overlay=false) 
length=input(14, "length")
ThreshStrong = input(2, "Strong Significant Bar")
ThreshWeak = input(1.4, "Weak Significant Bar")
TrueRange = at.tr
ATR = atr(length)
strongSB = tr > ATR*ThreshStrong
weakSB = tr > ATR*ThreshWeak
cold1=white
cold2=#b2ebf2
color = strongSB ? cold1 : weakSB ? cold2 : na
band1 = hline(ThreshStrong, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(ThreshWeak, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")
plot(tr, "true range", blue)
plot(ATR, "ATR", black)
plot(tr/ATR,"TR/ATR", red, style = histogram)
//plot(ma,"ma(TR/ATR)", green)
barcolor(color)

plot(close)
```

I copied this code from a fellow coder but it doesn't seem to work for me; my experience is very limited so im not having any luck getting it to work and hoping someone can point me in the right direction  -

i keep getting the following error 9:18:39 AM — Compilation error. Line 9: Syntax error at input 'TrueRange'

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for you

```
//@version=5
indicator("Significant Bar gku", shorttitle="Significant Bar", overlay=false) 
length=input(14, "length")
ThreshStrong = input(2, "Strong Significant Bar")
ThreshWeak = input(1.4, "Weak Significant Bar")
TrueRange = ta.tr
ATR = ta.atr(length)
strongSB = ta.tr > ATR*ThreshStrong
weakSB = ta.tr > ATR*ThreshWeak
cold1=color.white
cold2=#b2ebf2
color = strongSB ? cold1 : weakSB ? cold2 : na
band1 = hline(ThreshStrong, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(ThreshWeak, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")
plot(ta.tr, "true range", color.blue)
plot(ATR, "ATR", color.black)
plot(ta.tr/ATR,"TR/ATR", color.red, style = plot.style_histogram)
//plot(ma,"ma(TR/ATR)", green)
barcolor(color)

plot(close)
```